# How do I get context inside a companion object that is inside a data class Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, data-class, companion-object

I'm trying to use a resource string inside a companion object that is inside a data class. but I don't Know how to obtain context in that case in Kotlin.
Anyone knows how to do it?

```
data class PhoneCall(
val type: String,
    val code: String,
    val description: String){
companion object{
const val SOLUTION_NO_SOLUTION = "NO_SOLUTION" 
        const val SOLUTION_TOMORROW = "71_INAT"
        const val SOLUTION_TODAY = "72_INAT"

val solutions = listOf(
PhoneCall(Service.Traffic.PICK_UP, SOLUTION_NO_SOLUTION, Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.makeService))
)
}
```

I need to use a resource string in the 3 parameter, but I'm not able to get the context.

Comment: Can you add some code in the question? What are you trying to implement?

Comment: Hi, I added the code which I'm having problems

Comment: @Jesy You should never store `Context` inside a companion object. It leads to memory leaks and crashes. An alternative you can try is to store the resource Id in the `description` instead of the actual string. And replace it by string when you want to display this text (inside Activity or Fragment).

Comment: I need to use strings resources to use different languages, and inside val solutions I call 9 different string resources. Can you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify you `PhoneCall` model to store a string resource id instead of the actual string.

```kotlin
data class PhoneCall(
    val type: String,
    val code: String,
    @StringRes val description: Int
) {
    companion object {
        const val SOLUTION_NO_SOLUTION = "NO_SOLUTION" 
        const val SOLUTION_TOMORROW = "71_INAT"
        const val SOLUTION_TODAY = "72_INAT"

        val solutions = listOf(
            PhoneCall(Service.Traffic.PICK_UP, SOLUTION_NO_SOLUTION, R.string.makeService)
        )
    }
}
```

Then, when you need to display this data in the UI (say a TextView), you can fetch the string from the resource id.

```kotlin
descriptionTextView.text = getString(phoneCall.description)
```

Comment: What if you have PhoneCall class inside the domain module which is pure java? Is it possible return a resource or any reference? You cannot import androidx.annotation.StringRes